# Node : Set different domain name on different port

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, port, digital-ocean

I have created my website in node. where  I am using different port for different modules.

like
`http://localhost:5555/` this is for admin,

`http://localhost:5050/` this is for client access.'

I am using `Digitalocean` Ubuntu server and I have bought domains from `Godaddy`.

I want to set different domain on different port.

like

`http://localhost:5555/` should be "http://admin.example.com".

`http://localhost:5050/` should be "http://example.com".

I have tried with `nginx` in Ubuntu but doesn't get any useful.

Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did this with nginx on Ubuntu and faced no problems as such. What problem did you face?

Answer (score 1):

You need two `server` configs in your nginx config file, one for the admin subdomain and one for example.com itself. It should look something like this:

```
    server {
    listen          80 default;
    server_name     example.com .example.com ;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

and

```
   server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     admin.example.com;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```